# Передача контента из базы данных в FancyBox

Tags: база-данных, mvc, fancybox

В mvc приложении реализован метод, для получения изображения, хранящегося в базе данных

**C#**

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int id, string ch)
{
    var image = _imagesRepository.GetEnumerable.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);
    if (image != null)
    {
        return File(image.ImageData, image.ImageMimeType);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

В представлении необходимо показать изображение и передать fancyBox в случае клика по нему.

Для вывода изображения используется *Url.Action()*

**HTML**

```
@foreach (var image in item.Images)
{
    <div class="gal">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href='@Url.Action("GetImage", new{id = image.Id})' style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><img src='@Url.Action("GetImage", new{id = image.Id})' width="250px;" height="250px;" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Однако при клике по изображению fancyBox получает строку вызова метода получения изображения и в браузере возникает ошибка

*Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /Shop/GetImage?id=3*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможна ли в данном случае работа с изображениями, получаемыми из базы данных? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вариант решения задачи был предложен [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495299/fancybox-the-requested-content-cannot-be-loaded-please-try-again-later). В моем случае помогло изменение функции JS

**JavaScript**

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "iframe"
});
```